# База данных "Кинотеатр"

Tags: база-данных, проектирование

Выполняю задание, по проектированию схемы БД для кинотеатра(нужно спроектировать БД, находящуюся в 3 НФ и удовлетворяющую СБПИ), со следующем перечнем доступных документов: "Регистрация предварительной продажи билетов", "Билет", "Расписание сеансов", "Накладная на поставку фильмов". В результате выполнения работы получил следующую схему базы данных:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Меня смущает то, что обобщенный ключ получился лишь из одного атрибута. То есть, я так понимаю, моя схема БД удовлетворяет соединению без потерь информации? Может быть я неправильно построил множество ФЗ? Какие потенциальные проблемы могут возникнуть?

Comment: обобщенный ключ это составной что ли?

Comment: Обобщенный ключ это множество атрибутов, которые ничем функционально не определяются, я так понимаю.

Comment: Ну третьей формой тут даже не пахнет... Если два поставщика поставят один и тот же фильм, в таблице списка фильмов будет две практически идентичные записи, что ли?

Comment: Зачем покупать один и тот же фильм у двух поставщиков?

Comment: А вот это уже вопрос не по делу. Предметной областью не запрещено? значит, так будет. Всё, не обсуждается. Не, если надо как может быть в реале - поставили тебе фильм, покрутил ты его 2 недели. А через месяц взял ещё раз. У другого поставщика, ибо у него появилось с более дешёвой арендой.

Comment: Да, тоже об этом думал. То есть мне нужно добавить промежуточную таблицу, чтобы организовать связь "многие ко многим"?